# Sed command doesn't seem to process quote character properly

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a little issue with a sed command.
So I have a Dockerfile which contains the following:

```
LABEL maintainer="abc" \
    authors="abc" \
    version="1.0.0" \
    description="API desc..."
```

I'm trying to automate my release process so I have a script which increment the version in the Dockerfile before building it. Here's the `sed` command I use:

```
sed -r 's/(version=)([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9])/echo "    \1\\\"\2.\3.$((\4+1))\\\" "/ge' Dockerfile
```

The result is this:

```
LABEL maintainer="abc" \
    authors="abc" \
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

But as far as I can see all my strings are properly quoted. The `echo` itself has both opening and closing `"` and within the string itself I have both `\\\"` to print the `"` character itself. So I don't quite understand why I'm getting this error.

I have tried this

```
sed -r 's/(version=)([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9])/echo "    \1\\\"\2.\3.$((\4+1))\\\" \""/ge' Dockerfile
```

Where I added `\"` before the closing `"` of the `echo`: **\"**"/ge' and this actually works. Again I don't quite understand why this would work thought.

Thanks for your help

Comment: hmmmm ... I'm running `sed (GNU 4.4)` and neither of the `sed` commands generate an error nor do they generate a new version number

Comment: You are trying to execute arbitrary *shell* commands from inside `sed`; you can't do that.

Comment: With GNU `sed`'s `/e` flag you can, at least vaguely. It's not very portable so I would avoid it for that reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify the Dockerfile. The script that builds your image should pass the new version as an argument.

```
ARG version

LABEL maintainer="abc" \
      authors="abc" \
      version=$version \
      description="API desc..."
```

Then

```
docker build --build-arg version=<newversion> .
```

Whatever calls `docker build` is responsible for producing the next version number from the old one, which should be stored somewhere *outside* the Dockerfile.

This could be as simple as a single file that contains your version number, modified using `awk`:

```
$ cat version
1.2.3
$ awk -v OFS=. -F . '{$3=$3+1; print}' version > new_version && mv new_version version
$ cat version
1.2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some quotes:

```
sed -r 's/(version=)\"([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9])\"/echo "    \1\\\"\2.\3.$((\4+1))\\\" "/ge' Dockerfile
                    ^^                         ^^
```

Which outputs:

```
authors="abc" \
version="1.0.1"
description="API desc..."
```